# TFS 2010 isn't allowing access to the Documents folder in Team Explorer

Tags: team-foundation-server

After setting up TFS 2010 on a new server (running Windows Server 2008), everything seems to work fine, except for the Documents section of any TFS Project. When the TFS project is initially opened in Team Explorer, it shows "Documents (working...)" in the project tree, but it quickly changes to the image below. I cannot right-click on the Documents folder for a context menu.

[image: View of X over Documents folder]

I don't believe this to be a rights issue - the account I'm using is a Project Administrator.

Are there any other steps I can take to diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The documents folder is just a view on to the sharepoint site. Did you create the sharepoint site with the team project? If so have you added your account to sharepoint?